# Requirements text for gold tag badges is inconsistent?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-badges

The text on earing a tag badge from the [badges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges) page states:

> You must have a total score of 1000 in at least **200** non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

That is the correct requirement for a gold badge in any tag.

But when you click on the badge itself, it'll show the badges awarded in a specific badge:

> Earned at least 1000 total score for at least **80** answers in the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag

Bold emphasis, mine.

Comment: It's saying 20 answers for me.

Comment: @MBraedley you are right, its now 20 answers.  It was 80 when I posted this question.  Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  The original version hard coded the values which are different for different sited (e.g. child meta vs. main).  The new version will have the correct values to match.